# How to align two entries of a list that appears in the center of the page?

Tags: beamer, lists, environments

Using the Beamer Presentation template I am creating slides, my aim is to make a list environment with the bullet points aligned in the center of the page. How can I do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Possibility 1: Using `columns`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \begin{columns}
            \begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
            \end{column}
            \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item item1
                    \item item2
                \end{itemize}
            \end{column}
        \end{columns}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

### Possibility 2: Using `minipages`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \hspace*{.5\textwidth}
        \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item item1
                \item item2
            \end{itemize}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Edit:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \hspace*{.5\textwidth}
        \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item item1
                \item item2
            \end{itemize}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
        \hspace*{.1\textwidth}
        \begin{minipage}{.9\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item item1
                \item item2
            \end{itemize}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
        \hspace*{-.1\textwidth}
        \begin{minipage}{1.1\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item item1
                \item item2
            \end{itemize}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{frame}    

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Definitely, thanks for the answer. I thought of this but is there no other way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Added a second possibility

Comment: Thanks can I have it placed much more to the left by tailoring with the multiplier in front of the \textwidth? I tried .01 with .5 but it was still to the right of the location I intended to place it.

Comment: You can place it anywhere you want, see the edit